Why do I see likely invalid trait offer from Opensea API but not on the website's user interface?
Opensea has an API endpoint "Get trait offers" that should extract all the existing valid trait offers for a specific trait in an NFT collection. I will use the collection official-v1-punks, and the trait type: body and trait value: male as an example.

The following is one of the few strange items from the API output:
{
  "order_hash": "0xbbd271811d9b4e076759bb0eb583af94a0b47fd2989d330a62acf4baa259580e",
  "chain": "ethereum",
  "price": {
    "currency": "WETH",
    "decimals": 18,
    "value": "8650000000000000000"
  },
  "criteria": {
    "collection": {
      "slug": "official-v1-punks"
    },
    "contract": {
      "address": "0x282bdd42f4eb70e7a9d9f40c8fea0825b7f68c5d"
    },
    "trait": {
      "type": "Body",
      "value": "Male"
    },
    "encoded_token_ids": "1002:1003,1005:1009,1012:1013,1019:1020,1027,1031,1044,1053,1060:1061,1063,1069,1074:1075,1077,1091,1095,1097,1103,1105:1106,1108:1109,1113:1114,1116:1117,1127:1129,1143:1144,1146:1147,1153,1155,1160,1164,1166:1168,1170:1171,1175,1177:1179,1181:1185,1188:1189,1191:1195,1201:1202,1208,1211,1213,1215,1218:1219,1221:1223,1226,1228:1231,1235,1238:1242,1254,1257,1259,1266,1269:1271,1274:1275,1278:1281,1283:1284,1286,1290,1301,1303,1306:1307,1312,1314,1324,1331,1334:1338,1343:1344,1347:1349,1351,1358:1363,1365:1366,1370,1373,1375:1376,1378,1380:1381,1384:1385,1387,1391,1393:1398,1401:1406,1408:1409,1412,1423,1429:1430,1432,1435:1437,1439:1440,1443,1447,1451,1456,1459,1463:1466,1472:1474,1480:1484,1486,1490,1492,1497,1499,1502:1503,1505,1507,1510:1511,1516:1518,1522,1524:1525,1528,1530:1534,1536,1538:1541,1543,1546,1549,1551,1553,1557:1560,1564:1565,1567:1568,1570:1571,1575,1580:1581,1586,1589,1594,1597,1601:1602,1607,1611,1613:1615,1617,1622,1624:1625,1627,1632:1633,1638:1639,1641:1644,1646:1647,1650,1656:1657,1663,1665,1668,1673,1676:1677,1682,1686:1687,1690,1692,1695:1696,1698:1699,1701,1708:1709,1720,1728:1729,1731:1732,1741,1745,1753,1757,1762:1764,1767,1769:1771,1774,1777:1778,1781:1782,1784:1785,1787:1788,1790:1791,1802,1805,1808,1811,1814,1820,1823:1824,1830:1832,1834,1836,1840,1842,1845,1848,1851:1853,1858,1862,1867,1871,1874,1879:1880,1882,1884,1887,1889:1890,1896,1898:1899,1901,1904:1905,1912,1920:1923,1925,1927:1929,1933,1938,1941,1943,1945:1948,1950,1954:1955,1957,1960:1961,1964:1966,1968:1970,1973,1975:1976,1978,1981,1983,1987,1989,1991:1993,1995,1997,1999,2002:2006,2009,2011,2020:2021,2025:2026,2028:2029,2031:2032,2036,2038,2040,2042:2043,2048,2050,2055:2056,2058:2061,2063,2070:2071,2073,2075:2076,2079:2080,2084,2086:2088,2096,2099,2102,2108:2109,2111:2113,2116,2122,2126,2128,2130,2135,2141,2144,2147:2148,2151,2153,2155,2163,2165,2167,2172:2173,2175,2179,2185,2188,2191,2193:2194,2205,2209,2211,2215:2216,2220,2224:2225,2228,2230,2233,2235,2238:2239,2241:2242,2245,2248,2250,2254,2256,2258,2261,2263:2271,2276:2277,2280,2282,2285,2287:2292,2294:2296,2298,2301:2303,2307:2309,2311,2313:2315,2317,2320,2323,2325,2331:2332,2335,2337,2342,2345,2347:2349,2352,2354:2356,2362:2367,2369,2374:2379,2388,2392,2399,2402,2404:2405,2408,2412,2414:2415,2419,2421,2427,2437:2438,2440,2443,2446,2448,2453,2456:2458,2463:2466,2468:2473,2479:2480,2485,2489,2492:2493,2497:2499,2503:2504,2506,2509:2513,2518:2520,2522,2524,2528:2529,2535:2536,2538,2541:2542,2545,2547:2548,2550,2553,2556:2557,2564:2565,2567:2569,2571,2575:2576,2580,2582,2584:2587,2590,2592:2593,2595,2597,2599:2600,2603:2604,2606,2611:2612,2614,2616,2619,2625,2633,2635:2636,2639:2642,2644,2647:2648,2653,2655:2657,2661:2663,2665:2672,2674,2677:2679,2683:2685,2687,2689,2691,2693:2695,2699,2701,2718:2719,2724,2728,2732:2733,2738:2739,2744:2746,2748:2750,2752:2753,2757:2758,2762:2765,2767:2769,2771,2773:2774,2776:2777,2779,2783:2786,2788,2790,2801,2803,2806,2810,2818:2819,2823,2825,2827,2830,2833:2835,2838,2842,2848,2853,2855:2856,2862,2865:2866,2868,2870:2871,2875,2877,2880:2883,2886:2887,2892,2894:2895,2897:2899,2906:2908,2912,2921,2923,2936,2939,2942,2947:2948,2952,2955:2957,2959,2961,2965,2970:2971,2975:2976,2979:2980,2983,2985:2987,2989:2990,2993,2995:2996,2998:2999,3003,3007,3009,3013,3018,3020,3022:3023,3033,3039:3041,3046,3048,3052:3054,3056,3062:3064,3067,3069:3070,3072:3073,3077,3080:3081,3083,3085:3086,3090:3091,3094,3099,3103:3104,3106,3114:3115,3120,3122,3128,3130,3132:3134,3137:3138,3141:3142,3145:3146,3150,3152,3157,3160:3161,3168:3169,3171:3175,3181:3182,3184,3186,3188:3189,3191,3193:3196,3199,3203,3205:3206,3209,3213,3215,3218,3224,3228:3229,3234:3235,3238:3239,3243,3248,3255:3256,3260:3261,3268,3270,3272,3274,3276,3279,3281,3285:3286,3291:3292,3295,3297:3299,3309:3310,3312,3315,3317,3320,3322:3325,3327,3339,3342,3346,3349:3350,3352,3355,3357,3359,3362:3363,3365,3368:3370,3373:3374,3378,3381,3389:3390,3395,3403:3404,3407,3410,3419,3421,3423,3426,3428,3433,3438:3440,3444:3446,3448,3452,3454:3456,3458:3463,3467,3472:3473,3478,3482,3485,3491,3495,3497,3517,3523,3530,3532:3533,3536:3537,3544,3546,3549:3550,3552:3555,3559,3561:3562,3565,3568:3569,3571:3572,3575:3577,3579:3580,3583,3586,3591,3596,3599,3612,3619,3622,3624:3626,3630,3634:3635,3643,3647,3652,3655,3657,3660:3662,3665,3667,3670,3676:3677,3680:3683,3690,3693,3695:3696,3698,3708,3713,3717,3727,3729:3731,3736:3738,3740,3744:3745,3748,3751:3754,3759:3762,3766,3769,3771,3776,3778:3780,3782:3783,3792,3794,3797,3801:3802,3804,3808,3813:3815,3817,3819,3822,3833:3838,3840,3843:3847,3851:3852,3855,3878,3880,3886,3893,3897,3901,3903:3907,3915:3917,3925,3929:3930,3933,3936,3941:3943,3945,3952:3953,3955:3956,3958,3960,3963,3966,3971:3973,3977:3980,3982:3983,3987,3989:3990,3992:3994,4000,4002:4003,4005,4011,4013,4017,4023:4025,4033,4035,4041,4049:4053,4057,4059,4063:4064,4066,4068,4071,4076:4077,4079,4081:4082,4084,4090:4091,4094,4096:4098,4102,4104,4108,4111,4119,4121,4123,4126,4128,4136,4138,4142,4150,4155,4157,4160,4162,4164,4171:4172,4174:4175,4181:4182,4185:4187,4189,4192:4193,4197,4199,4202:4206,4209,4216:4217,4226,4228,4238,4244,4248,4252:4253,4255:4256,4271:4272,4280,4282:4285,4287,4289:4293,4295:4299,4303,4307:4308,4311,4322,4326,4336:4338,4341,4350,4355:4356,4359:4361,4369:4371,4373,4375,4378:4379,4384,4391:4392,4394:4395,4399,4404,4408,4411,4413,4419,4422,4425,4427,4431,4433,4436,4445:4447,4452,4454,4457:4458,4460,4462,4466,4469:4471,4473:4480,4482:4484,4487:4488,4490,4492:4493,4497,4499,4503,4505,4507:4509,4511,4519:4520,4522:4523,4527,4529,4531:4534,4551,4555:4558,4561,4567,4572,4581,4583,4587,4589,4591:4592,4596,4600:4601,4604:4605,4610,4618,4620,4640,4642,4644:4651,4653,4661,4663,4667,4669,4672,4679:4680,4684,4688:4689,4692,4694,4701,4703,4705:4709,4713:4715,4717:4718,4720,4723:4725,4727:4728,4730:4737,4739,4741,4743:4746,4748:4750,4753:4755,4757:4760,4762,4764:4766,4770:4771,4773:4777,4780:4781,4783,4785:4786,4789:4796,4804,4808,4810,4818,4822,4825,4827,4836:4838,4841:4845,4847,4853:4856,4858,4861,4864,4866:4867,4875:4876,4878,4888,4897,4901:4902,4905:4907,4913,4915,4917:4918,4923,4925:4926,4932:4933,4939:4940,4942,4944,4951,4953,4955,4962,4967,4969,4971,4987,4991:4994,4999,5002,5008,5015:5018,5021:5023,5028:5029,5031,5033:5035,5037,5039,5041,5046:5048,5057:5059,5061,5063,5065,5070,5077:5078,5080,5087,5089:5090,5098,5101,5103:5104,5113,5122:5123,5128,5131,5136,5141:5145,5148,5151,5163,5169:5170,5184:5185,5188:5189,5194,5197,5201,5205:5207,5209,5213:5214,5218,5220,5225:5228,5230:5231,5235,5239,5246:5247,5252,5255,5261:5262,5268:5269,5274,5286,5289,5292,5296:5297,5309,5311,5313,5322,5324,5328:5329,5334:5335,5337,5341:5342,5349,5355,5360,5362,5364,5366,5368,5370,5374,5377:5379,5381,5393,5395,5410,5416,5418,5420,5424,5427,5437,5439,5443:5444,5448,5450,5453,5455:5456,5458:5459,5463,5465,5472:5473,5478:5479,5488,5491,5494,5498,5510,5520:5521,5523,5526:5530,5533,5536,5543,5546:5549,5558:5559,5561,5568:5569,5575,5581:5582,5584,5586,5588,5596,5602:5604,5606,5614,5617:5618,5627,5632:5633,5653,5655,5657,5661:5662,5664,5674,5676,5678,5683,5687,5690,5694,5699,5701,5705,5707,5710:5711,5716,5718,5722,5729,5736:5737,5740:5741,5746,5749:5750,5752,5755,5760,5762:5763,5767:5768,5773,5776:5777,5780,5786,5789,5792:5793,5799,5802:5803,5807,5810,5812,5818,5845:5846,5854,5859,5861:5862,5864:5868,5870:5871,5874,5876,5882,5886:5887,5889,5892,5894,5907,5910:5911,5915,5920:5922,5925,5936,5943,5948,5953,5956:5957,5959,5962:5965,5968:5969,5973:5975,5979,5981,5984:5985,5987,5994,5996:5997,5999,6013:6014,6018,6020,6031:6032,6034:6035,6039,6041:6042,6046,6048,6054,6056,6058,6061:6062,6066,6068:6069,6076,6080,6083,6085,6087,6090,6095,6108:6109,6112,6114,6117:6121,6123,6130,6134,6137:6138,6151,6153,6156,6159,6166:6168,6171,6174,6176,6180:6181,6185,6188:6189,6192:6193,6195,6198,6203,6207,6211:6214,6217:6219,6225,6229,6233,6236,6240,6247:6248,6251,6266,6269,6276,6279,6283:6284,6287,6299,6308,6311,6314,6317:6318,6325,6332,6336:6337,6349,6351,6353:6356,6359,6361:6364,6366,6372:6375,6380,6382,6387,6391:6393,6397:6398,6400,6410,6412:6414,6427,6437,6439,6443,6446,6449,6459,6471:6472,6477,6489,6492,6502,6507:6508,6511,6517,6521,6525,6533,6538:6542,6545,6548,6551:6553,6561:6562,6567,6575,6591,6596:6597,6599,6607,6615,6617,6619,6622,6628,6630,6632:6636,6641:6643,6645:6648,6652:6653,6655,6657,6660:6661,6669:6673,6675,6679,6683:6684,6689,6693:6694,6697,6709,6717,6719,6722,6725,6737,6742,6745:6746,6750:6751,6755:6756,6758,6760,6771:6772,6778,6781:6782,6787:6790,6792,6798:6799,6802:6803,6819,6830,6832:6833,6838:6839,6841,6843,6846,6849:6850,6852:6853,6857,6869,6871,6873:6874,6876:6877,6883,6887,6889,6891,6894,6899,6901,6907,6911,6913,6917,6920:6921,6925,6934,6938,6940,6943,6947:6949,6952:6953,6955:6956,6959,6962,6967:6968,6971,6976,6980,6983,6985,6987,6989,6995,6999,7001,7003,7005,7021,7025:7026,7029:7030,7032,7040,7046,7048:7049,7051,7054,7060,7062,7065,7067,7075,7080,7084,7088:7089,7091:7092,7096,7098,7109,7112,7115,7117:7119,7129:7130,7134,7137,7139,7143:7144,7146,7149,7151,7154,7159:7161,7164,7167:7168,7173,7175,7178,7182,7186:7190,7192:7193,7201,7207:7208,7213,7215,7220:7221,7231,7233,7236,7239,7241:7242,7245:7247,7253,7255,7264:7265,7268,7270,7273:7274,7276:7279,7283,7290,7293,7297:7298,7308,7310,7313,7319:7321,7323,7329,7331:7332,7334,7339,7345,7347,7349:7351,7353,7355,7357,7359:7360,7363,7372,7377,7382:7384,7386,7393,7399,7403:7404,7408,7416:7418,7425,7427,7431,7433:7435,7438,7442,7451,7454,7462:7463,7467,7477,7479,7481,7487:7492,7496,7505,7507,7513:7514,7517,7519,7524,7527,7529,7533,7537:7539,7541,7543:7544,7547,7549,7558:7559,7561,7564:7567,7569,7571,7573,7579,7581,7584:7585,7591:7592,7596,7598,7605,7607:7608,7612:7614,7618:7619,7621,7627:7628,7632:7633,7635:7636,7642,7647,7655:7656,7658,7665,7667:7669,7671:7675,7677,7679:7681,7683:7688,7691,7696:7697,7699,7704:7706,7708:7709,7711,7716:7717,7721,7724:7726,7728,7730,7737,7742,7748,7753,7757,7759,7762,7764:7766,7769,7771:7772,7774:7776,7779,7781,7783:7784,7789,7796,7799,7807,7809,7816:7819,7837,7845,7858,7863,7867,7871,7873,7878:7879,7883,7890,7892:7893,7895:7896,7905,7908,7910,7913,7921,7923,7925:7926,7931,7936,7939,7947:7948,7950,7952:7956,7959:7964,7968:7969,7984,7986,7988,7992,7995,8000,8004,8006,8011:8013,8016,8019,8021,8031,8040,8047:8050,8053,8056,8059,8062,8065,8067,8070,8075,8078:8081,8083:8086,8099,8101,8107,8113:8114,8116,8120:8123,8129,8131:8132,8139,8143:8144,8146,8151,8153,8155,8157,8163,8165,8170:8171,8175,8177:8182,8185,8189,8197:8198,8202,8208,8210,8212,8214,8226:8227,8234,8236,8242,8244:8245,8258:8259,8262,8264,8266,8283,8291:8292,8301,8305,8313,8325,8327:8328,8333:8335,8337,8339,8341,8353,8355,8358:8359,8362,8366,8371:8373,8375,8378:8381,8383,8385,8390,8393,8395:8396,8398,8402,8408:8410,8415,8430,8442,8446,8448:8449,8451:8453,8455,8457,8459:8460,8462:8464,8471,8474,8476:8478,8480:8482,8488:8491,8494,8507:8508,8521:8522,8525,8532,8534,8542:8543,8546:8547,8551,8554,8557:8559,8561,8564,8568,8571:8573,8575,8581,8590:8591,8601,8606:8607,8609:8615,8620,8622,8624:8628,8632:8633,8637,8642:8645,8648,8651,8653:8655,8659:8661,8664,8666,8671:8672,8682,8684,8687,8703,8706,8710:8711,8714,8717,8720:8721,8724,8730,8734,8738,8740,8748,8751,8753,8756,8758,8761:8762,8778,8781,8785,8788:8789,8791,8796,8798,8801,8808,8811:8812,8815,8820:8821,8823,8825:8827,8830:8834,8838,8844,8853,8859,8869:8871,8875:8878,8881:8882,8892,8894,8899:8901,8913,8918,8920,8925:8927,8930,8938,8940:8941,8945:8947,8951,8963,8965,8968:8971,8979,8984,8988,8991,8996,9007:9008,9010:9012,9019,9022,9024,9026,9031,9039,9046:9049,9054:9056,9059,9061:9062,9065,9070,9072,9075:9077,9079:9080,9082,9084:9085,9087:9090,9092:9094,9096:9101,9103,9106,9110,9112:9113,9115,9119,9130,9133,9135,9137,9139:9141,9144,9150,9156:9157,9165,9174,9185,9187,9189,9192,9198,9204,9206,9210,9212,9218,9222,9225,9231,9233,9235,9238,9243,9246,9255,9259:9260,9263,9277,9279,9281:9282,9284,9291,9293,9296:9297,9305:9306,9319,9321:9322,9328,9336:9337,9342:9346,9357,9363:9364,9372,9374,9378,9380,9384,9386,9389,9391,9394,9404,9407,9415:9416,9418,9420,9425:9427,9444,9447:9448,9453,9458,9462,9464,9467,9475:9478,9496,9502,9504,9519,9521,9528,9542,9547,9557,9564:9565,9567,9574,9578,9580,9585,9589,9596,9601,9603,9610,9612,9616:9617,9622,9624,9626,9628,9636,9643,9649,9656:9657,9664,9666:9667,9673,9687,9690,9698,9700:9705,9708,9718,9720:9721,9723,9728,9733,9736:9737,9739,9744,9751,9753,9759,9764:9766,9772,9785,9790,9802,9811:9812,9815:9816,9822:9823,9826:9827,9829:9830,9847,9855,9859,9862,9872:9873,9878:9879,9886:9887,9893,9900:9902,9904,9910,9913:9916,9918,9922,9944,9946:9948,9950:9951,9962,9968,9972:9973,9975,9978:9979,9984:9986,9988,9992:9993,9996"
  },
  "protocol_data": {
    "parameters": {
      "offerer": "0xb8f41a794bbe5f3cbfd8f1e15193523f0294897e",
      "offer": [
        {
          "itemType": 1,
          "token": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
          "identifierOrCriteria": "0",
          "startAmount": "8650000000000000000",
          "endAmount": "8650000000000000000"
        }
      ],
      "consideration": [
        {
          "itemType": 4,
          "token": "0x282BDD42f4eb70e7A9D9F40c8fEA0825B7f68C5D",
          "identifierOrCriteria": "96231353907059522259188739067227604257214053597156751087025889692911960325312",
          "startAmount": "5",
          "endAmount": "5",
          "recipient": "0xB8f41A794bbE5F3cbfD8F1E15193523f0294897e"
        },
        {
          "itemType": 1,
          "token": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
          "identifierOrCriteria": "0",
          "startAmount": "216250000000000000",
          "endAmount": "216250000000000000",
          "recipient": "0x0000a26b00c1F0DF003000390027140000fAa719"
        }
      ],
      "startTime": "1730586899",
      "endTime": "1733178896",
      "orderType": 3,
      "zone": "0x000056F7000000EcE9003ca63978907a00FFD100",
      "zoneHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "salt": "0x360c6ebe00000000000000000000000000000000000000004c0a69668ef0423e",
      "conduitKey": "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
      "totalOriginalConsiderationItems": 2,
      "counter": 0
    },
    "signature": null
  },
  "protocol_address": "0x0000000000000068f116a894984e2db1123eb395"
},

The address 0xb8f41a794bbe5f3cbfd8f1e15193523f0294897e has made a trait offer to all male Cryptopunks V1 at 8.65 WETH, from start time 2024-11-02 16:34:59 to end time 2024-12-02 15:34:56. And checking against Zerion.io, this wallet does have more than his WETH bid to cover it.

However, the current highest bid for male is 2.022 WETH

Assuming this is not an error on Opensea's database backend, what are the plausible explanations as to why the bid is shown only in the API endpoint but not on Opensea UI? How can I identify and filter these invalid bids out?
